# Rearranging terms for $x$ involving $e^x e^y = (1 + e^x)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How can we solve this equation for $x$?
$$4e^x e^y = ( 1 + e^x)^2$$

I got stuck with this problem.
It took a lot of time, however, each time unable to solve.

Attempt:
put e^x = u i.e, x = ln(u)
$$4u e^y = ( 1 + u)^2$$
$$4u e^y = 1 + 2u + u^2$$
$$0 = u^2 + (2-4e^y).u + 1$$
$$ 2u = -(2-4e^y) +-     \quad \sqrt{(2-4e^y)^2 - 4} $$
$$ 2e^x = -(2-4e^y) +-     \quad \sqrt{(2-4e^y)^2 - 4} $$
$$ ln2 + x = ln[-(2-4e^y) +-     \quad \sqrt{(2-4e^y)^2 - 4}] $$

Then again it stuck!

Any help will be truly appreciated!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, some MathJaX formatting would really help here, so we can read it more easily.

Comment: Your subject and question disagree. Is there a $4$ there or not?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews 4 is a constant, we can just ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $u=e^x$, then we get a quadratic equation $4ue^y=(1+u)^2$ which you can solve with the quadratic formula. Then back substitute for $x$.

Comment: Many thanks, but, when i tried, the quadratic solution is more complicated than the given problem,

Comment: "you can solve with the quadratic...." What word did you intend to use after that?

Comment: @BhishanPoudel The question asks to solve for $x$. So doesn't that suffices?

Comment: @Bhishan now you can simply back substitute. The answer will be extrememly ugly, but it will work

Comment: @Displayname I got it, thanks.